# Looking for a generalised or non-iterative maths equation for the process of slicing up a range value

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose I have a integer range $[0,n]$ and an integer $x$ within that range.

Suppose I can generate an integer $y$ though this iterative process:

1. $x$ is converted to Base 2
2. For each bit from most to least significant:

   - If 0 then cut the current number range in half, keeping the upper half as the new range.
   - If 1 then cut the current number range in half, keeping the lower half as the new range.
3. Once there are no more bits, $y$ is the current value of $n$.

*Is there a maths equation that can solve for $y$ without this iteration?*

*Indeed, is there any generalised equation or known algorithm for this behaviour?*

<sub>N.B. Feel free to change the question title if you know the type of equation or algorithm this is.</sub>

Comment: A solution to this will act as a partial solution to a crypto stack exchange [question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/19641/8209).

Comment: What happens when we "run out of range", i.e. if we have too many bits?  For example, what does $1110_2$ return on $[0,4]$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Well, if $x$ is within range $[0,n]$ hopefully that won't happen. Although once the range becomes $[a,a]$ the process could bail as all subsequent steps would have the same result for a non-fractional integer range.

Comment: I forgot $x$ was in $[0,n]$, my mistake.